# D3.enter().merge() not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im working on getting the General Update pattern in V4 to work, and though I believe I understand the new workings of it with `merge()`. Im experiencing strange results. Here is my update function:

```
function update(data) {

    //I create and empty selection, and use the key function with an ID string
    //in my dsv data.
    var bubs = dataLr.selectAll(".data-bub")
        .data(data, function(d) {
            return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

    //remove any that dont need to be there.
    //The first time around there wont be any nodes in the exit, but no matter.
    bubs.exit()
        .transition(tIntro)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .each(function(d) {
            //Log out the removed elements.
            console.log(d.id);
        })
        .remove();

    bubs.enter() //add any new ones - a group and a circle within it.
        .append("g")
        .classed("data-bub", true)
        .on("click", function(d) {
            console.log(d);
        })
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 20)
        .classed("bub", true)
        .merge(bubs);//here I merge the enter with the update.


    //Now I should be able to run this transition that 
    //moves each group to a random location on my svg.
    //But nothing happens. Why is the update selection empty after merge?
    bubs.transition(tIntro)
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            ///console.log(i);
            var y = Math.random() * gHeight;
            var x = Math.random() * gWidth;
            return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
        });

}
```

Furthermore, another wierd thing keeps happening. Currently Im running this function without changing the data. So no elements should be getting removed on `exit()` or `enter()`. Yet two random ones are removed and re-added each time? What the devil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.merge()` does not change the selection - in d3v4 selections are immutable. So once declared, a selection will always remain the same, unless you redefine it. If your initial `selectAll` method returns an empty selection, `bubs` won't have an anything in the udpate selection - until you redefine `bubs`. All merge does is:

> Returns a new selection merging this selection with the specified
>   other selection. ([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection))

If you were simply appending `g` elements, then you could use:

```
bubs.enter() 
    .append("g")
    .merge(bubs)
    // apply transition to enter and update selection
    .transition()...
```

Or alternatively, redefine `bubs` with the selection returned by merge:

```
bubs = bubs.enter() 
    .append("g")
    .merge(bubs);

// apply transition to enter and update selection
bubs.transition()....
```

But you will run into problems with your code in that you have two selections of two different types of elements: the initial seletion of `selectAll(".data-bub")` - which selects `g` elements based on your code, and a selection of entered circles:

```
bubs.enter()         
    .append("g")               // return entered g elements
    .classed("data-bub", true) // return entered g elements with class data-bub
    .append("circle")          // return entered circles
    .merge(bubs);              // return entered circles with initially selected g elements
```

If you apply a transition to the merged elements your transition will be applied unevenly - to the parent `g` elements in the case of an update and to the child `circle` elements in the case of entering. This could lead to undesired results (for example if you also have child text elements). To solve this problem (and apply a transition to `g` elements both entered and updated), you could try something along the lines of:

```
    var bubs = dataLr.selectAll(".data-bub")
        .data(data, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

    // remove as before
    bubs.exit()
       .remove();

   // enter new groups
   var enter = bubs.enter()  
      .append("g")
      .classed("data-bub", true);

   // append circles to the new groups
   enter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 20)
        .classed("bub", true)

   // merge enter and update, apply transition
   enter.merge(bubs)
      .transition()....
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion but the transform is being applied to the circles and not larger group, resulting in craziness. Ill try v2. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed that your selection which you were using merge with was a selection of `circle`s - not of `g` elements - I've updated to acknowledge that. v2 is dated and lacks in documentation, I'd try to avoid it if possible.

Comment: This is working. adding each selection to a variable nreally drives home for me that each selection is immutable.  But my second problem still remains. Two elements are being added and removed each time this update function is run, despite the fact that the input data has not changed. All that should be happening is the transition to new locations of the existing elements.

Comment: If you remove the keying function in .data() does it continue to do so? It is possible that `i` is incrementing for datums where id is not defined - without seeing your data, I'd probably say two elements in the data array don't have ids.

Comment: (that wasn't as clear as I'd like: if `i` isn't reset each time you use .data(), then the keys will be different each time you run the update function and items will be removed and entered, assuming that d.id is not defined in each datum) Using `.data(data)` should be able to confirm if keys are the issue.

Comment: I removed the key function and it still happened. And double checked that all do have id property. In fact Im logging the ids of both enter() and exit() elements and its just printing the same two id's over and over again.

Comment: This is unlikely as it occurs without the key function, but could there be an overlap in ids, from the API docs: "if multiple elements have the same key, the duplicate elements are put into the exit selection; if multiple data have the same key, the duplicate data are put into the enter selection". Also are there other elements with the class `data-bub`? Sorry for the lack of certainty - without being able to reproduce this specific problem it is difficult to definitively solve it.